# How to use cross-validation method in Tensor-Flow

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision, convolution, cross-validation

I'm trying to use cross-validation in Tensor-flow . i write this semi code as my algorithm

```
Database{
    Class1=12000
    Class2=20000
}
TrainBatch=
{
    Class1=11000
    Class2=18000
}
TestBatch=
{
    Class1=1000
    Class2=2000
}
epoch=5000
while(Epoch>0)
{
    K=10
    Shufle(TrainBatch);
    Devide TrainBatch To 10 Batch For Cross Validation;
    for (i=1;i=k;i++)
    {
        V=Fetch (ValidateBatch[i]);
        T=Fetch (TrainBatch-V);
        Y=TrainWithTensorflow(T);
        Validate(Y,V);
        SaveDetail();
    }
    Epoch--;
}

Final Test(Class1=1000,Class2=2000);
```

but i don't know how to combine Cross-validation and tensor-flow training parameters in one algorithm.

is method is correct ? or
can anyone correct this method ?

Comment: This pseudo code looks correct. Why can't you implement this by passing correct data with `feed_dict`?

Comment: i didn't  implement yet. but i am confused how to batching data for feed Tensor-flow. is necessary to divide T in small batch? And i don't know this method is valid in machine learning or not . for example maybe this method make over-fitting?

Comment: I remember reading this in the Deep Learning book, it will help you if you have limited data. Have you read any of the standard tensorflow tutorials?

Comment: no i cant find any tensor-flow sample  to using cross-validation

Comment: Not specifically for crossvalidation, but you can find generic tutorials to split data using `numpy` and feed it to tensorflow's `feed_dict`?